Pip installs packages globally inside of virtual environment
I am wanting to install a python package locally and have currently set up a virtual environment via the terminal commands  "python3 -m pip list; python3 -m venv venv; venv/bin/pip list" with the below output:
Space Invaders/start python3 -m pip list; python3 -m venv venv; venv/bin/pip list

Package           Version
----------------- ---------
arcade            2.6.17
attrs             23.2.0
cffi              1.16.0
Pillow            9.3.0
pip               24.0
pip-autoremove    0.10.0
pycparser         2.22
pyglet            2.0.dev23
pymunk            6.4.0
pytiled-parser    2.2.0
requests          2.31.0
setuptools        69.0.2
typing_extensions 4.12.2

Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.3.1
setuptools 69.0.2


Which seems correct until I install a package within the activated the environment:
Space Invaders/start source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) Space Invaders/start python3 -m pip install arcade

(venv)   Space Invaders/start pip list

Package          Version
---------------- ---------
arcade           2.6.17
attrs            23.2.0
cffi             1.16.0
Pillow           9.3.0
pip              23.3.1
pycparser        2.22
pyglet           2.0.dev23
pymunk           6.4.0
pytiled-parser   2.2.0
setuptools       69.0.2
typing_extension 4.12.2

Upon deactivating the environment, running the command "venv/bin/pip list" shows the settings of the global packages instead of the packages installed when pip is installed into the virtual environment output:

Package           Version
----------------- ---------
arcade            2.6.17
attrs             23.2.0
cffi              1.16.0
Pillow            9.3.0
pip               23.3.1
pycparser         2.22
pyglet            2.0.dev23
pymunk            6.4.0
pytiled-parser    2.2.0
setuptools        69.0.2
typing_extensions 4.12.2


How can I make sure that pip only installs packages within the virtual environment and not refer to global packages?

Please don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

I'm not sure how I could have emphasised that pip has referred to two different environments in installing packages without my direct input.
I believe the images showed a visual cue to show the depth of the issue.
Definitely appreciate the feedback to better engage with Stack Overflow

I'm sorry, I just realised Stack Overflow offered a suggested edit. Thank you for bringing this to my attention

I don't get why your second output somehow shows that the package was installed globally. You are still in the venv, running pip list in the environment at it shows more packages than before

Type deactivate, then type pip list. What happens?

As expected pip list shows a global package list outside of the virtual environment.
I'm wanting to install arcade in my local environment. Sorry for not being able to communicate a general problem without context.

Well, it would be useful to have all that debugging data in your question.

I have made edits to my question in respect to these comments

You need to activate your virtual environment
>> python3 -m venv .env  # create venv

>> source .env/bin/activate  # activating venv

>> which python3  # path to python. Should be in venv folder
/path/to/your/folder/.env/bin/python3

>> which pip  # path to pip. Should be in venv folder
/path/to/your/folder/.env/bin/pip

>> pip list  # list all packages inside env
Package Version
------- -------
pip     24.0

>> pip install requests  # install library
...

>> pip list  # list of libraries inside venv
Package            Version
------------------ --------
certifi            2024.7.4
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
idna               3.7
pip                24.0
requests           2.32.3
urllib3            2.2.2


>> deactivate  # leave from venv and use system python

>> which python  # path to python. Here should be in /usr/bin or similar global path
/usr/bin/python 

>> pip list  # list packages in global python. Should not be the same as in venv
...



I have started the virtual environment and which python and which pip shows that the files are located inside the ".env/bin" directory, however pip list still shows the globally installed packages.
For completeness, upon deactivating, which pip, and which python shows that the commands are being called from the "/usr/local/bin" directory

can you show output of the next commands?
python3 -m pip list;
python3 -m venv venv;
venv/bin/pip list

I have updates my question with your feedback, thanks

ok. what about source ./venv/bin/activate; python3 -m pip list?
I think that you have some alias for pip command the call system pip instead on venv pip

Sorry all, it appears that what happened was I forgot to uninstall Arcade's dependencies from the global environment, I may have overlooked the dependencies before reaching out for help on why Arcade's dependencies were appearing locally.
